# Crystal Reports on ASPX page navigation not going past page 2, can't move to page_init because of filter controls on the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have this issue with Crystal Reports in which paging buttons don't navigate past page 2. Here is my scenario:

- ASP.NET 4.0 project
- CR Developer Version 13 SP16
- Data source is cached in session throughout page loads
- Report is controlled via filters on ASPX page
- Filter values are passed on to a stored procedure on the DB itself at databind

I have already gone through other similar posts both here and on the internet which basically tell me to move report initialization from Page_Load to Page_Init, but there's a difference here: on Page_Init, I don't have access to the filters allowing me to control the report yet, which means I can't query them for filter data. I have also tried other things, including enabling viewstate and moving report binding to the Navigate event, but to no avail. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I fixed it myself by passing the parameters via session. It's crude and I had to remove autopostback functionality in the process, but it works.